# In hadoop,what is the difference and relationship between jobtracker tasktracker?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

as the title says,In hadoop,what is the difference and relationship between jobtracker tasktracker? Can someone explain to me ,thanks for your kind help!

Comment: First result on google: http://hadoopinrealworld.com/jobtracker-and-tasktracker/

Answer (score 2):

### Job Tracker –

- JobTracker process runs on a separate node and not usually on a DataNode.
- JobTracker is an essential Daemon for MapReduce execution in MRv1. It is replaced by ResourceManager/ApplicationMaster in MRv2.
- JobTracker receives the requests for MapReduce execution from the client.
- JobTracker talks to the NameNode to determine the location of the data.
- JobTracker finds the best TaskTracker nodes to execute tasks based on the data locality (proximity of the data) and the available slots to execute a task on a given node.
- JobTracker monitors the individual TaskTrackers and the submits back the overall status of the job back to the client.
- JobTracker process is critical to the Hadoop cluster in terms of MapReduce execution.
- When the JobTracker is down, HDFS will still be functional but the MapReduce execution can not be started and the existing MapReduce jobs will be halted.

### Task Tracker-

- TaskTracker runs on DataNode. Mostly on all DataNodes.
- TaskTracker is replaced by Node Manager in MRv2.
- TaskTracker will be in constant communication with the JobTracker signalling the progress of the task in execution.
- Mapper and Reducer tasks are executed on DataNodes administered by TaskTrackers.
- TaskTrackers will be assigned Mapper and Reducer tasks to execute by JobTracker.
- TaskTracker failure is not considered fatal. When a TaskTracker becomes unresponsive, JobTracker will assign the task executed by the TaskTracker to another node.